# Python analyzing a specific area in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi

This is a conveyor belt and my area of interest is the orange strip:

[image: image of conveyor belt]

I have a camera system that would take pictures of the conveyor belt with its products on it. The amount of pictures are 500-2000 images per production run. What I need to ensure is that the orange strip of the conveyor belt is always clear of any objects and is not obstructed so the production runs smoothly. There's more context to this but just know that in the picture I need the orange strip to be orange, and if its not, that means its obstructed.

So i need to have a program where it can read the images and analyze both of the orange strips in the picture so when they detect anything that's obstructing the strip, it will send an error message. What I have in mind is that the program will have rectangles at the top and bottom of the image where the orange strips are at and when it's obstructed, an error message will show in the image.

I have no clue what this process is called but currently im looking at hough transform, template matching and colour detection. The issue i'm facing is that since the orange strip is continuous, the code reads numerous duplicates at the image which would overlap each other. and the entire image would just be coloured.

What i'd like is just to have it analyze in a rectangle at the top and bottom strip which would be a 2/3 length of the image from the centre. Please help and if it's not clear, please don't hesitate to ask for the details that you need.

Edited: Added a picture of an example of obstruction. The white dots could be dust or any impurities.

This is an example of an obstruction:
[image: example of obstruction]

This is my progress so far:
[image: progress segmentation]

I would like to analyze the area at the red rectangle only if possible.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
import cv2
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('sample02.jpg')                   # Read image
img = cv2.resize(img, (672, 672))                    # Resize image     
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_gray = np.array([0, 0, 0], np.uint8)
upper_gray = np.array([0, 0, 45], np.uint8)
mask_gray = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_gray, upper_gray)
img_res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask_gray)
cv2.imshow('detected.jpg', mask_gray)
cv2.imwrite('5.jpg',mask_gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Finally able to isolate the 2 bars And detect foreign matter]

Im able to isolate the bars and the foreign matter/obstruction is shown clearly

This is the code that i used:

```
# importing cv2 
import cv2 
import numpy as np

# Reading an image in default mode 
img = cv2.imread('f06.bmp')                   # Read image
img = cv2.resize(img, (672, 672))             # Resize image     
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_gray = np.array([0, 0, 0], np.uint8)
upper_gray = np.array([0, 0, 45], np.uint8)
mask_gray = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_gray, upper_gray)

# 1) Start coordinate (Top rectangle)
# represents the top left corner of rectangle 
start_point = (0, 0) 
# Ending coordinate
# represents the bottom right corner of rectangle 
end_point = (672, 200) 
# color in BGR 
color = (0, 0, 0) 
# Line thickness 
thickness = -1

# 2) Start coordinate (Mid rectangle)
start_point2 = (0, 240) 
# Ending coordinate
# represents the bottom right corner of rectangle 
end_point2 = (672, 478) 
# color in BGR 
color2 = (0, 0, 0) 
# Line thickness  
thickness2 = -1

# 3) Start coordinate (Bottom rectangle)
start_point3 = (0, 515) 
# Ending coordinate
# represents the bottom right corner of rectangle 
end_point3 = (672, 672) 
# color in BGR 
color3 = (0, 0, 0) 
# Line thickness 
thickness3 = -1

# 4) Start coordinate (Left rectangle)
start_point4 = (0, 180) 
# Ending coordinate
# represents the bottom right corner of rectangle 
end_point4 = (159, 672) 
# color in BGR 
color4 = (0, 0, 0) 
# Line thickness
thickness4 = -1

# 5) Start coordinate (Right rectangle)
start_point5 = (485, 0) 
# Ending coordinate
# represents the bottom right corner of rectangle 
end_point5 = (672, 672) 
# color in BGR 
color5 = (0, 0, 0) 
# Line thickness
thickness5 = -1

# Using cv2.rectangle() method 
image1 = cv2.rectangle(mask_gray, start_point, end_point, color, thickness) 
image2 = cv2.rectangle(mask_gray, start_point2, end_point2, color2, thickness2) 
image3 = cv2.rectangle(mask_gray, start_point3, end_point3, color3, thickness3) 
image4 = cv2.rectangle(mask_gray, start_point4, end_point4, color4, thickness4) 
image5 = cv2.rectangle(mask_gray, start_point5, end_point5, color5, thickness5) 

image = image1 + image2 + image3 + image4 + image5

# Displaying the image 
cv2.imshow('test.jpg', image)
cv2.imwrite('almost02.jpg',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It's a little rigorous and long cause i manually inserted rectangles at the areas im not interested in since i've already used mask but there's still a lot of noise. so this is the best that i could come up with.

It's able to count the white pixels now!

The code i used to count the white pixels:

```
img = cv2.imread('almost05.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
n_white_pix = np.sum(img == 0)
print('Number of white pixels:', n_white_pix)
```

[image: tested with pictures that are good and bad. The good would have more white pixel counts which would range from 437000-439000 and the bad would have less at 435000-436000]

I'll have to play around with the dilation or other parameters to make the difference more apparent so to avoid a false positive.

Comment: It is quite clear what you are trying to accomplish, but it is not clear what you have tried and what your results are.
Please provide 1. code 2. exact input 3. required output for that input.

Comment: That said, why not just segment the orange area by pixel color + some simple morphological hole filling? just check what is roughly orange in the image. wouldn't it be enough? why not?

Comment: Please add some example images with obstructions.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have added an example of obstruction

Comment: @Gulzar basically i just copied code from youtube videos and online sites. https://pythonprogramming.net/template-matching-python-opencv-tutorial/ its similar to this but since what im trying to detect is a line, the yellow boxes are infinitely overlapped to each other

Comment: Add your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start testing with the simplest possible options first, then add other features on top if required.

Here are a couple of ideas to test:

**1. colour detection**

- Use [`cv2.inRange()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html) to segment the two orange bars
- Use [`cv2.countNonZero`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.countNonZero) to count the number of orange pixels before any occlusions
- If there is an occlusion there will be less orange pixels: you could use a threshold value with a bit of tolerance and test

**2. connected components with stats**

- Use `cv2.inRange()`to segment the two orange bars
- Use [`cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga107a78bf7cd25dec05fb4dfc5c9e765f) to isolate the orange bars
- Use the stats (width, height area) to check if there are indeed two orange bars with the expected width / height ratio (otherwise, if that doesn't occur and there are more connected components from the orange bars than two potentially something is in the way)

You could so something similar with [`findCountours()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html) (and you could even fit ellipse/rectangles, get angles and other metrics), but bear in mind it will be little slower on a Raspberry Pi. Connected Components is a bit limited, working with pixels only, but is faster and hopefully good enough.

Here's a super basic example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cv2
import numpy as np

# test image (4 corners, a ring and a + at the centre)
src = np.array([
    [255,255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,255,255],
    [255,  0,  0,255,255,255,  0,  0,255],
    [  0,  0,255,  0,  0,  0,255,  0,  0],
    [  0,255,  0,  0,255,  0,  0,255,  0],
    [  0,255,  0,255,255,255,  0,255,  0],
    [  0,255,  0,  0,255,  0,  0,255,  0],
    [  0,  0,255,  0,  0,  0,255,  0,  0],
    [255,  0,  0,255,255,255,  0,  0,255],
    [255,255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,255,255]
    ],dtype="uint8")

# connectivity type: 4 (N,E,S,W) or 8 (N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW)
connectivity = 8
# compute connected components with stats
(labelCount,labels,stats,centroids) = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(src, connectivity)
# number of labels
print("total number of labels",labelCount)
# labelled image
print("labels")
print(labels)
#  stats
print("stats")
print(stats)
# centroid matrix
print("centroids")
print(centroids)

# visualise, 42 = (255 // (labelCount-1))
labelsVis = (np.ones((9,9),dtype="uint8") * labels * 42).astype('uint8')
cv2.imshow('labels',labelsVis)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# just connected components (no stats), 4 connectivity
(labelCount,labels) = cv2.connectedComponents(src, 4)
print("labels")
print(labels)
```

**3. Use a ROI and image differencing / background subtraction**

Given static camera/lighting, if you're simply interested if something goes outside the bounds you could do something like:

- [mask](http://#!/usr/bin/env%20python%20import%20cv2%20import%20numpy%20as%20np%20%20#%20test%20image%20(4%20corners,%20a%20ring%20and%20a%20+%20at%20the%20centre)%20src%20=%20np.array(%5B%20%09%5B255,255,%20%200,%20%200,%20%200,%20%200,%20%200,255,255%5D,%20%09%5B255,%20%200,%20%200,255,255,255,%20%200,%20%200,255%5D,%20%09%5B%20%200,%20%200,255,%20%200,%20%200,%20%200,255,%20%200,%20%200%5D,%20%09%5B%20%200,255,%20%200,%20%200,255,%20%200,%20%200,255,%20%200%5D,%20%09%5B%20%200,255,%20%200,255,255,255,%20%200,255,%20%200%5D,%20%09%5B%20%200,255,%20%200,%20%200,255,%20%200,%20%200,255,%20%200%5D,%20%09%5B%20%200,%20%200,255,%20%200,%20%200,%20%200,255,%20%200,%20%200%5D,%20%09%5B255,%20%200,%20%200,255,255,255,%20%200,%20%200,255%5D,%20%09%5B255,255,%20%200,%20%200,%20%200,%20%200,%20%200,255,255%5D%20%09%5D,dtype=%22uint8%22)%20%20#%20connectivity%20type:%204%20(N,E,S,W)%20or%208%20(N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW)%20connectivity%20=%208%20#%20compute%20connected%20components%20with%20stats%20(labelCount,labels,stats,centroids)%20=%20cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(src,%20connectivity)%20#%20number%20of%20labels%20print(%22total%20number%20of%20labels%22,labelCount)%20#%20labelled%20image%20print(%22labels%22)%20print(labels)%20#%20%20stats%20print(%22stats%22)%20print(stats)%20#%20centroid%20matrix%20print(%22centroids%22)%20print(centroids)%20%20#%20visualise,%2042%20=%20(255%20//%20(labelCount-1))%20labelsVis%20=%20(np.ones((9,9),dtype=%22uint8%22)%20*%20labels%20*%2042).astype(%27uint8%27)%20cv2.imshow(%27labels%27,labelsVis)%20cv2.waitKey(0)%20%20#%20just%20connected%20components%20(no%20stats),%204%20connectivity%20(labelCount,labels)%20=%20cv2.connectedComponents(src,%204)%20print(%22labels%22)%20print(labels)) the central region of the conveyor belt, leaving only the top and bottom areas including the orange bands visible and store (in memory or disk) an image with no objects on the orange bands
- in the main processing loop do [absolute difference](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.absdiff) between the new masked camera frame and original one stored previously
- any objects in the way would be white on a black background: can use `countNonZero()` / `connectedComponentsWithStats()` / `findCountours()` / etc. to setup the threshold condition.

OpenCV comes with a pretty decent [Background Subtractor](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html). Might be worth a try though it will be more computationally expensive and you'll need to tweak the parameters (history size, rate at which it forgets the background, etc.) to best suit your project.

You're on the right track. Personally I wouldn't bother with template matching for this task (I'd save that for detecting icons on a desktop or a very stable scenario where the template to search with will always look the same in the target image when present in the image). I haven't had enough good experiences with [HoughLine](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html): you could try it, find the right parameters and hope the line detection remain consistent.

Comment: This is sooo helpful i can't thank you enough. This is my first time dealing with code and it's a little overwhleming but i'm trying my best. I'll give all these a try and get back to you on my progress. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the vote and kind words. Another minor note on masking: an alternative might be using two regions of interest ([ROI](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#image-roi)) (top and bottom, including orange bands) and processing each ROI, however it doesn't anything extra to the mask idea: it's just another way of looking at the problem. Good luck

Comment: Thank you. Big fan of your bash/ImageMagick answers btw :)

Comment: Hi @GeorgeProfenza i've tried for almost a week now and i'm stuck at the stage where i need to isolate the 2 lines. I've updated my progress above. I managed to detect the 2 lines using cv2.inRange but there are still 'noise' thats included and i've no clue how to mask it anymore as i've played around with the tuple. I'm also at a lost on how to properly code the cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats() and cv2.countNonZero as i did mange to count the number of pixels of the image but as you can see, there are many black and white pixels. What i would like is to have it count the area i highlighted

Comment: @Xeno Thank you for posting the code snippet and images. It's useful. I now realise there's an extra bit of information that would come in handy: [using morphological filters](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html). In your case try having a play with `cv2.dilate()`  (or `cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)` where `kernel` is square structuring element: e.g. `cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,5))` ) should get read of the black pixels on the mostly white bars.

Comment: You might also want use a [trackbars](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_trackbar/py_trackbar.html) for the parameters you use (e.g. upper/lower range / dilate amount, dilate kernel size, etc. ) to test/prototype faster. (Also no need to for matplotlib at this point as far as I can see)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza im finally able to isolate them! now comes the analysis part. at the state of the updated picture, is it possible for me to do cv2.countNonZero and count the total number of white pixels from the entire image and create a range. lets say on average there should be 200-250 white pixels and if theres less than that, that means there's an obstruction? would that be the best approach? or would that be risky? since the white bar itself is never the same size there could be false errors. would deep learning be feasible? I apologize for being difficult and the repetitive questions.

Comment: Well done! Ideally you want to have a segmented image with just those orange bars appearing as white and the rest completely black. With such an in image, if you add up the area of the two bars in pixels it should be close to what `cv2.countNonZero` would return. Bare in mind, depending on dilation, noise in the camera and other factors it's unlikely this will be an exact number each time, however there will be a range when there are no obstructions and what `cv2.countNonZero` returns *should* be smaller than this range. The danger is with false positive: you want to avoid a threshold value...

Comment: ...that is so close to that will throw of detection. I've noticed the images you posted have inconsistent dimensions and your snippet riszes the image. Try to keep things consistent and at least proportional. It's worth understanding the fundamentals of computer vision before jumping into deep learning. You can use deep learning of course, but it depends on what restrictions you have deploying this system. You can easily prototype using something like [teachable machine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/) and providing enough examples that to get reliable results

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thank you for pointing out the image sizes! and yes this was an issue initially cause the images i got were of different sizes cause of the camera setup, and because the images are in a secure folder, i had to snip them, thats why they're different sizes here xD but in the code ive added a resize line which would make all the images proportional so that fixed the issue. And im able to count the no. of white pixels! i tried with countzero but the code was a little complex. i found a much shorter and clean code online which worked perfectly (as updated above)

Comment: And thank you for introducing me to teachable machine! i'm playing around with it now and i'll try some other methods. im almost there but i've got 3 more steps to do. i'm trying to figure out how i can read the images automatically since new images will be taken, and the name of the image would be different always so how can i make the code know to read those new images. also, how can i save the images in a server with a new name always. and finally, how i can 'teach' or code it so that the system can dictate which is a pass and which is a fail. I'll update when I have news! Thank you again